# Why does static_cast not use the conversion operator to pointer to const?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, casting, implicit-conversion

From my wrapper class `Pointer<Base>` I'd like to only return pointers to const: `Base const *`.
When casting `Pointer<Base>` to `Derived const *` I get a compile error:

> error C2440: 'static_cast': 'Pointer' can not be converted to 'const Derived *'

(translated from german VS2012)

```
struct Base { };

struct Derived : public Base { };

template <typename T>
class Pointer {
public:
    Pointer(T *t = nullptr) : p(t) { }

    //operator T*() { return p; }
    operator T const *() const { return p; }

    template <typename U>
    inline U staticCast() const { return static_cast<U>(d); }

private:
    T *p;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Derived d;
    Pointer<Base> p(&d);

    Derived const *pd = static_cast<Derived const *>(p);
}
```

If I enable the conversion `operator T*() { return p; }` it works.

Why doesn't `static_cast` use the const conversion operator?

Or more specifically, since

```
Derived const *pd = static_cast<Derived const *>(static_cast<Base const *>(p));
```

works:

Why can `static_cast` implicitly cast to `Base *`, but not to `Base const *`, even though the latter is sufficient for the cast target type?

---

[The standard says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

> If there is an implicit conversion sequence from expression to new_type, or if overload resolution for a direct initialization of an object or reference of type new_type from expression would find at least one viable function, then static_cast(expression) returns the imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type Temp(expression);, which may involve **implicit conversions**, a call to the constructor of new_type or **a call to a user-defined conversion operator**.

[Emphasis by me]

---

**Workaround**

Since this seems like a VisualStudio bug, I will use a workaround instead by means of a templated member function `staticCast()` (see sample code above), to be used like this:

```
Derived const *pd = p.staticCast<Derived const *>();
```

To allow only casts to `U const *`, use SFINAE:

```
template <typename U>
struct is_pointer_to_const
{
    static const bool value = std::is_pointer<U>::value
            && std::is_const<typename std::remove_pointer<U>::type >::value;
};

template <typename U>
inline U staticCast(typename std::enable_if<is_pointer_to_const<U>::value >::type* = 0) const
{ return static_cast<U>(d); }

template <typename U>
inline U staticCast(typename std::enable_if<!is_pointer_to_const<U>::value >::type* = 0) const
{ static_assert(false, "Type is not a pointer to const"); return U(); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one conversion allowed, so you can convert to `Base`, but it cannot be converted afterwards to `Derived`.

So you have to use two consecutive casts. It's safer anyway because you state that you know that you are converting from a `Base` to a `Derived`. You should never have an implicit conversion from a base class to a derived class.

Comment: Then I should also need the two-step cast if I allow implicit conversion to `Base *`, but that compiles fine.

Comment: What Martin's saying is that you haven't explained why the other approach works.

Comment: Well, it doesn't on coliru, so you would need to be more precise.

Comment: So it seems this is a VisualStudio specific implementation detail?

Comment: If you mean bug, then perhaps, yes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to process in two steps as you're trying to convert `Pointer<Base>*` ---(1)---> `Base const*` ---(2)---> `Derived const*`, with:

1. `Pointer<Base>::operator Base const*`
2. downcast.

e.g.

```
Base const* pb = static_cast<Base const *>(p);
Derived const *pd = static_cast<Derived const*>(pb);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f2dafb8132d4682).

Comment: "If I enable the conversion `operator T*() { return p; }` it works." What's the difference?

Comment: Additionally, the first line wouldn't need a `static_cast`, that's exactly what the conversion operator is there for: `Base const* pb = p;`

Comment: @MartinHennings [CNR](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8869a77cdb9f298 "Could not Reproduce"), is it an(other) MSVC bug?